# How to select distinct IDs from a table that matches two similar columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table of data:

```
+-----+-----------+------------------------------------+---------+
| ID  | post_type | name                               | term_id |
+-----+-----------+------------------------------------+---------+
| 278 | supplier  | Heating                            |      15 |
| 282 | supplier  | Central Heating                    |      16 |
| 278 | supplier  | Biomass                            |      17 |
| 278 | supplier  | Ground Source Heat Pumps           |      18 |
| 278 | supplier  | Passive Solar                      |      19 |
| 282 | supplier  | Air Source Heat Pumps              |      21 |
| 278 | supplier  | Air Conditioning                   |      22 |
| 278 | supplier  | Boilers                            |      23 |
| 277 | supplier  | Lighting                           |      25 |
| 277 | supplier  | LED's                              |      26 |
| 282 | supplier  | Halogen                            |      28 |
| 277 | supplier  | CFL                                |      29 |
| 282 | supplier  | Sustainable Construction Materials |      31 |
| 282 | supplier  | Plaster                            |      33 |
| 282 | supplier  | Floors                             |      37 |
| 282 | supplier  | Water                              |      38 |
| 282 | supplier  | Showers &amp; Baths                |      43 |
| 278 | supplier  | Cooling                            |      44 |
| 278 | supplier  | Refrigeration                      |      46 |
| 282 | supplier  | Passive Design                     |      47 |
| 278 | supplier  | Chillers                           |      48 |
| 282 | supplier  | Renewable Energy                   |      49 |
| 282 | supplier  | Air Source Heat Pumps              |      53 |
| 282 | supplier  | Biomass Heating                    |      55 |
| 282 | supplier  | Biofuels                           |      57 |
| 282 | supplier  | Insulation                         |      61 |
| 282 | supplier  | Wall                               |      63 |
| 282 | supplier  | Floor                              |      64 |
| 282 | supplier  | Draught Proofing                   |      65 |
| 282 | supplier  | Energy Efficiency                  |      70 |
| 282 | supplier  | Gas Boiler Management Systems      |      71 |
| 282 | supplier  | Low Energy Lighting                |      72 |
| 282 | supplier  | Voltage Control                    |      73 |
| 282 | supplier  | Smart Meters                       |      74 |
| 282 | supplier  | Electric Heating                   |      75 |
+-----+-----------+------------------------------------+---------+
```

And need to extract a list of `ID`s that apply to BOTH a specified `name` (wildcard string) and a `term_id` (integer). So for example I'd search for the `ID`s that have a `name LIKE '%Lighting%'` and a `term_id = 26`...which should return `ID 277`.

The following query works but isn't pretty:

```
SELECT a.ID, d.name, d.term_id
FROM cn_posts AS a
INNER JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
INNER JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id
INNER JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
AND d.name LIKE '%Lighting%'
AND a.ID IN (
    SELECT a.ID
    FROM cn_posts AS a
    INNER JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
    INNER JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
    WHERE d.term_id = '26'
)
GROUP BY a.ID
```

I've tried the following queries but they all return no results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, d.name, d.term_id
FROM cn_posts AS a
LEFT JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
LEFT JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id
LEFT JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
AND d.name LIKE '%Lighting%'
AND d.term_id = '26'

SELECT a.ID, d.name, d.term_id, a.post_status
FROM cn_posts AS a
JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id 
JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
AND d.name LIKE '%Lighting%'
AND d.term_id = '26'
GROUP BY a.ID
```

These both return posts:

```
SELECT a.ID, d.name, d.term_id, a.post_status
FROM cn_posts AS a
JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id 
JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
AND d.name LIKE '%Lighting%'

SELECT a.ID, d.name, d.term_id, a.post_status
FROM cn_posts AS a
JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id 
JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
AND d.term_id = '26'
```

But when you include both the name and term_id in the query it returns nothing?

Comment: Changing AND to OR is the logical solution to the problem as stated. Oh you'd remove the brackets so
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish' AND d.name LIKE '%Halogen%' AND d.term_id = '25'
If that doesn't work please post what actually happens when you do this.

Comment: Hi Dale, thanks for the quick reply. Updated the question to include the new query, doesn't return anything though

Comment: @daveaspinall Perhaps an obvious one, do you definitely have something in your table which is halogen and id of 25?

Comment: try: WHERE name = "Halogen" and term_id = "28"

Comment: @Clev231 thanks for the reply. yea there records in the database that match

Comment: @Chanckjh im afraid the name needs to be like as its based on a keyword search. was there a reason for this though? to test its not the wildcard thats breaking it?

Comment: Also added a query to the question that seems to work? Is this the best way to go or is there a prettier/faster way to do this? Cheers, Dave

Comment: @daveaspinall can you give me the exact names of the tables before WHERE.So remove everything from WHERE

Comment: you also forgot to add a.post_status in SELECT

Comment: @Chanckjh I've included the mysql results for the select with no where statements apart from post_type (so you only see the relevant posts) to the question above, hope this helps!

Comment: Your more comprehensive data sample doesn't seem to correlate as well with the paragraph just under it as the initial, shorter sample did. Having read the original version of the post, *I think* I now understand your problem better, but I can't be sure. Could you perhaps just show what output you are expecting for the data sample posted?

Comment: @AndriyM hey, thanks for the reply. I've updated the question to both match the table of data and to specify exactly what I'm after. Thanks!

Comment: I think we also ned to see the structure (And sample data ) of the other tables involved

Comment: This is the structure: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png (standard wordpress tables). Think the issue was with the join of the second terms table as both terms tables were the same after they were joined, so the term_id which we also need to match didnt exist in the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, no single row in the table (your data sample) matches the condition of `d.name LIKE '%Lighting%' AND d.term_id = '26'`. There are rows matching the first part and those matching the second part, but none matching both. However, if taken as a *group* of rows, the `ID = 277` does match the condition. Therefore, you need to introduce grouping and apply the condition, albeit slightly modified, in the HAVING clause, like this:

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM cn_posts AS a
INNER JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
INNER JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id
INNER JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY a.ID
HAVING COUNT(d.name LIKE '%Lighting%' OR NULL) > 0
   AND COUNT(d.term_id = '26'         OR NULL) > 0
;
```

Note, however, that this means you can't obtain the details like `d.name` or `d.term` alongside the IDs in the same query (but pulling other columns from `a` would be all right in this case). If returning the `d` columns in the same query is mandatory to solving your problem, you'd likely need to use the above as a derived table in an almost identical query that pulls *all* the data you need. The derived table would in that case be used as a means of filtering down the set of IDs to just those matching both conditions. And in that main query, the two conditions would need to be connected with `OR` rather than with `AND`, like this:

```
SELECT a.ID, d.name, d.term_id
FROM cn_posts AS a
INNER JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
INNER JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id
INNER JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
AND (d.name LIKE '%Lighting%' OR d.term_id = '26')
AND a.ID IN (
    /* the above query, now used just as a filter */
    SELECT a.ID
    FROM cn_posts AS a
    INNER JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
    INNER JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
    WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
    GROUP BY a.ID
    HAVING COUNT(d.name LIKE '%Lighting%' OR NULL) > 0
       AND COUNT(d.term_id = '26'         OR NULL) > 0
)
;
```

Apparently, this would hardly be better than the query you've ended up.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, really appreciate it! Theres another possible option (joining the cn_terms table twice) that would be easier since it gets all the fields but if that doesn't work I'll be using this. Thanks again, Dave

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
SELECT a.ID, d.name, d.term_id
FROM cn_posts AS a
INNER JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
INNER JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id 
INNER JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
AND d.name LIKE '%Lighting%'
AND d.term_id = '28'
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is that not the same as my query above? (the first update with the bracketed AND statement? cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID, d.name, d.term_id, a.post_status
FROM wp_posts AS a
JOIN wp_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id 
JOIN wp_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
AND d.name LIKE '%Halogen%'
AND d.term_id = '25'
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for this, had to modify to table prefixes but returns empty unfortunately

Comment: @daveaspinall remove after WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'. Do you get a list with publish?

Comment: removed the group by and where post status but still no results. looks like they're cancelling eachother out so thats why the query with to select statements works?

Comment: remove after where a.post_status = 'publish'. So remove AND d.name.... I want to know if you get a list with publish, because I think there is no a.post_status where the names are 'publish'

Comment: updated your answer to show results after removing the AND statements, which shows there are records that match, thanks again for your help

Comment: I see in your list that halogen is 28. change 25 to 28

Comment: Updated the question again, tried your query with the correct id but still no results, but they each work if you either just select a name or id, but not together :-/

Answer (score 0):

Cant this simple select will not do waht you need.

```
select ID, name, term_id from yourtable where name LIKE '%Lighting%' and a term_id = 26
```

Answer (score 0):

After all the help from everybody (thankyou very much!!) I ended up just using this query which wasn't the cleanest but the only one that got the results I was after and I needed to get the job moving.

Also matches the keyword on post title and description as well as the service name.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, a.post_status, d.name, d.term_id
FROM cn_posts AS a
JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id
JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish'
AND ( a.post_title LIKE '%Lighting%' OR a.post_content LIKE '%Lighting%' OR d.name LIKE '%Lighting%' )
AND a.ID IN (
    SELECT a.ID FROM cn_posts AS a
    INNER JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
    INNER JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id
    WHERE d.term_id = '26' )
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Thanks so much for all your help. Obviously if you can figure out why the other queries didn't work or can clean up this one feel free to reply.

Dave

Comment: Do `d.name` or `d.term_id` need to be in the output? From your description, it does seem a little as though you primarily need `cn_posts.ID` and maybe other accompanying attributes from `cn_posts`. There's another approach that would allow you to grab at the IDs without repeating almost the entire query twice, but it wouldn't get you the details like columns from `d` and other tables apart from `a`. So the question is whether you could do without the other columns.

Comment: If I removed the other fields, I'd still have the list of ID's from which I could grab the data from later so yes if theres a simple query to just get those that would be fine

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID, d.name, d.term_id 
FROM cn_posts AS a 
INNER JOIN cn_postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id 
INNER JOIN cn_term_relationships AS c ON a.ID = c.object_id 
INNER JOIN cn_terms AS d ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_id 
INNER JOIN cn_terms AS d2 ON c.term_taxonomy_id = d2.term_id 
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish' 
AND d.name LIKE '%Lighting%' 
AND d2.term_id = '26'
```

Since your conditions are on different rows, you have to join to the cn_terms twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This makes sense, but still returned 0 rows? Cheers